# PayPal Integration - IOS/Swift

Tags: paypal

I am developing an app where users have to make appointments. In order to successfully book an appointment, they have to pay via PayPal or credit card. However, the SDKs for PayPal have been deprecated for a while. The alternative I am seeing, is integrating PayPal using Braintree. Will this alternative work for me being located in the Caribbean? If not, what other alternative is there for me to integrate payments via PayPal/credit card?

Answer (score 0):

Express Checkout via Braintree SDKs will work. It uses credentials from https://developer.paypal.com / https://www.paypal.com -- not https://braintreepayments.com

Here is the guide: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/accept-payments/express-checkout/ec-braintree-sdk/get-started/

Comment: Thank you for your response. Would it be possible to pay without a paypal account using this implementation, like the previous mobile sdk?

Comment: It will be a normal PayPal Checkout. An existing account is never required, but depending on the merchant and the buyer, one might need to be creating after card details are entered.

Comment: Managed to get the express checkout, but the option to just enter credit car info is not showing. It prompts the user to sign in to their paypal account in order to proceed to checkout. I also have Paypal Optional enabled in my account preferences. So im guessing my location is the reason for this.